# Define a value-type to a select element in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

As I tried to look around for an answer, And I couldn't find one, although it may be very simple.

I am doing an `HTML` form, with a `select`element. where the value is supposed to be a number, (going with a `POST` method straight into the Data-Base).

I am getting an error as the DataBase complaints that the value is text, and it has to be an integer.

Now, my question is, is it possible to define `value="number"` as we can do with an `input` element?

Comment: How are you connecting to the database? What have you tried?

Comment: May be show us some code or error what have you tried so far?

Comment: Everything is fine, the DataBase is connected. My question is only `HTML` related, I want to be able to `post` a number value with the form

Comment: In that case I guess the answer provided by @Quentin should suffices your requirement.

Comment: You might be reading the input as a string on the server side. You may want to parse an integer out of it, and insert it to the database. More details about the way you connect to the database would help solve the issue.

Comment: Okay, I see the answer of @Quentin, and I will have to do it manually in the back-end (I am using Node.JS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any kind of data submitted from a form is going to be text (if we ignore file inputs in multipart forms at least). This includes `<input type="number">` (which just stops the *text* from including non-number characters).

If you want to make sure that the data is a number then perform type conversion on the string when it gets to the server.